# “Tell” as in “Tell me a song you like!”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

How do I translate *tell* as in the title? It has a slightly different meaning than, for example, as in *tell me a story* (*erzählen*). The story is directly what you tell, while the song is what you tell *about*. (And also different from *tell me about a song you like*.)

Comment: [Please state why a dictionary didn't help you](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=tell&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)

Comment: @Jan In the list you linked there is no way to tell (no pun intended) which translation of "tell" is good for "stories" and which one is good for "songs" (using the examples of the question). They both fall into the category of "telling someone something". Also, I believe my example ("tell me a song") is quite a rare use of "tell", hard to find in online dictionaries.

Comment: I linked the list because I know the correct word is rather high up there. But I was also hoping you would go through the list, ideally think what the different words meant and maybe narrow down the possibilities from *everything* to *would it be correct to use X because it also means Y which can convey a similar meaning?*

Comment: @Jan Alright, let me rephrase the question... Is *erzählen* correct in this case? Because it usually means *tell* as in *tell me a story*.

Comment: @Jan Because _nennen_ is missing in the list you linked to?

Comment: @Matthias *sagen* is *by far* the more idiomatic choice imho.

Comment: @Jan, not in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use *sagen*:

> Sag' mir ein Lied, das dir gefällt.
>   *Tell me a song you like*.
>
> Sag' mir, was du letztes Wochenende
>   gemacht hast.
>   *Tell me what you did last weekend.*

In a rather formal context, you can also use *nennen* (to name):

> Nennen Sie mir bitte Ihren Namen.
>   *Tell me your name, please*.
>
> Nennen Sie drei Ihrer Stärken.
>   *Name three of your strengths.*

Comment: These are the two options I'd recommend, too. Only that I think that _Nenne mir ein Lied..._ would be the more idiomatic (and by no means formal) translation for _Tell me a song_.

Comment: I disagree with the notion of *nennen* being more idiomatic. I can *only* really imagine people using *sagen*, and would reserve *nennen* entirely for the formal option.

Comment: I think it depends on the region. Living in Southern Germany, I hardly ever hear anybody say "Nenne mir…" in an oral (and relaxed) conversation.

Comment: Just to add my two cents to the discussion. I'd go with "Sag mal ein Lied". First, "sagen" is way more idiomatic than "nennen" to my mind (regarding this example). Second, I wouldn't add that they should say it *to me*. This is implicit.